# Save realtime data on client vs on server

Tags: real-time

I need to implement a site with a real-time graph.

I'm currently using WebSockets and chartjs.org for displaying the values.

Now I'm not sure whether I should send all data points in every message or just only the new data points and save the remaining data points on a client-side ring buffer.

In the current setup I need to send about 200-3200 data points per second.

I'm currently favoring sending all data points at once to keep the U/I stateless. But I have the fear that performance will degrade because of the higher needed data throughput.

Comment: I think you can break the points in some blocks and write a script in client to request the blocks via async requests (maybe 10 blocks per graph) and get more connections with less data in each call. In the server side, if you had to find the missing points to send back to each client, maybe let your code more complex and less eficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a separate realtime notifications service built for scalability, such as [PushRadar](https://www.pushradar.com), realtime performance will not drop because you broadcast more data points at the rate at which you describe.

Regardless of whether you use an external service or not, if you are fetching the existing data points from a data source such as a database, I would recommend broadcasting only the new data points to avoid multiple DB calls. Otherwise, if you generate all the data points at runtime, you can afford to send them all over (and it is easier to do so as you don't need to store anything client-side).

Disclaimer: I am the Founder of PushRadar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved my problem by creating a library that does the buffering for me. The UI then gets the buffered object, so its completely stateless. See http://github.com/marco-a/object-buffer